# Custom domains for Azure Web App

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up multiple custom domains for our web app.

Basically it's a dynamic website that checks the url and displays specific content based on the customer determined by the url.

Let's say we have contoso.com our customer.

In order for the website to work we need and A record poiting to our server ip provided by Azure and a TXT record poiting to mywebsite.azurewebsites.net.

But this is not enough, we also have to go to Azure portal, and add the Hostname there, 'contoso.com', otherwise our customer will get a 404 error.

My question is, can we tell Azure, our web app, to accept any hostname, not only the ones defined in the Azure portal?

I know we can add hostnames via powershell or rest api, but we have thousands of customers and is just too much to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible.  Just think, you can have multiple sites running on the same VM and they'll all have the same IP address.  The service requires each site to register it's hostname ahead of time so that when a request comes in, the service knows which site the request should be routed to.

Comment: I'd upvote again if I could, for sure as Azure is a shared platform it's not possible for you to just accept any domain, you have to define them so the underlying Azure infrastructure knows what to accept or reject.